# AVCaptureMetaDataOutput: detect more than four (4) QR codes

Tags: ios, avfoundation, qr-code, augmented-reality

[TN2325](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2325/_index.html) says:

> Can AVCaptureMetadataOutput detect multiple 2-Dimensional barcodes in a frame?
>   Yes. There is a limit of four barcodes.

In my app, I'm using QR codes as fiducial trackers to detect the position of objects in the  scene seen by the camera (*see below*), and 4 simultaneous objects are not enough. Before I head down the path of integrating some other QR tracking code, has anyone found a way of making AVCaptureMetadataOutput detect more than 4 trackers?

**Example Scene**
[image: Example]

**Tried and failed approaches**

I tried dividing the screen into 10 regions (that are overlapping by 50%), and then reading one rect every 0.2 seconds, and joining the results of each region. Terrible: slow, loses track of markers, markers keep ending up on region boundaries. Code for that approach: https://gist.github.com/nevyn/7153525

I tried making ten AVCaptureMetadataOutput and adding them to the same session. Doesn't work: you can only have one output of each kind on a session.

I tried making ten AVCaptureSessions with a MetadataOutput each. Doesn't work: you run out of memory.

**Third party libraries**

So, giving up on AVCaptureMetadataOutput, I tried some third party libraries. All failures:

- [ZXingObjC](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC) only supports a single code in the scene.
- [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/index.html) is not good enough at scanning codes; only if the code takes up the majority of the screen is it able to detect it.
- [Studierstube Tracker](http://handheldar.icg.tugraz.at/stbtracker.php) looks great, but doesn't even seem to be available for commercial use o_o

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I need to scan a QR Code which has some other codes close next to it. I've been looking for some information but there's not a lot around for iOS.

Comment: @Jasper: I was suggested an alternative idea. Capture camera to an image buffer. Scan that buffer instead. Every time a marker is found, cover the marker with black. Scan again. Keep scanning and covering until all markers are found. Collect the results. No idea if it would work, as I had to abandon this project :( If you do try it, please report the result!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. ZBar is a great library but not the best for blurry QRCodes in combination with the older camera of the iPad2. After we optimised the QRCode sharpness and did some more testing we found out the minimum size a QR has to be for the iPad2 to detect it. I'm not sure if we will still have to do more work on this but it's a nice approach if we have to do so. I'll let you know.

Comment: @Jasper what is the minimum size of QR code that you found will get detected by iPad2? I have run similar tests with iPhone 6 that I have and for a 256 character QR code, it can scan upto 8mm qr codes.

Comment: @BK would love to help you out, but can't even remember the project that was on. I'm not into development anymore either.

Comment: Fair enough, this was a 4 year old post, anyways thanks.